# MySQL specifying exact order with WHERE `id` IN (...)

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, in-clause

Is there an easy way to order MySQL results respectively by WHERE `id` IN (...) clause?
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articles.id IN (4, 2, 5, 9, 3)
```

to return

```
Article with id = 4
Article with id = 2
Article with id = 5
Article with id = 9
Article with id = 3
```

and also

```
SELECT * FROM articles WHERE articles.id IN (4, 2, 5, 9, 3) LIMIT 2,2
```

to return

```
Article with id = 5
Article with id = 9
```

Update: to be more specific, I want to avoid tampering with the data in parentheses in `WHERE articles.id IN (4, 2, 5, 9, 3)`, since those IDs are dynamic and automatically ordered.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yeah, kind of:

```
SELECT * FROM articles
WHERE articles.id IN (4, 2, 5, 9, 3)
ORDER BY FIND_IN_SET(articles.id, '4,2,5,9,3')
```

but this is non-standard SQL and smells a bit.

Comment: +1 for pragmatic solution. And for the "smells a bit" part. ;)

Answer (score 5):

This works for me: 
**ORDER BY FIELD(Product.id, 4,9,8,5,3,11,24,16)**

Comment: This both works and is actually faster than the accepted answer, on my machine anyway. I tested with 1000 records and `find_in_set` took 0.03 seconds and `field` took 0.02 seconds. I suppose this difference would become more marked with larger sets. I also tested with a "LIMIT 2" clause and `find_in_set` actually took longer, 0.04 sec, whereas `field` still took 0.02 sec. Personally I think 0.02sec is still pretty slow. The OP should be careful to not pass in large data sets or he will take a performance hit!

Answer (score 1):

MySQL only sorts with ORDER BY.  This is why it's not terribly uncommon for database tables to have something like an ordinality column.

```
articles
+----+------------+-------+
| id | ordinality | (...) |
+----+------------+-------+
|  2 |          2 |    '' |
|  3 |          5 |    '' |
|  4 |          1 |    '' |
|  5 |          3 |    '' |
|  9 |          4 |    '' |
+----+------------+-------+

SELECT *
  FROM articles
 WHERE articles.id IN (4, 2, 5, 9, 3)
 ORDER BY articles.ordinality
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. There's no "explicit" ordering going on; the "in" statement simply tells you what to retrieve, and has no information about ordering.

Since the examples you've given have no obvious order, your best bet is to handle this in code after the result is returned.